# Mathing multiple strings by using python 're' module

Tags: python, regex

I have simple format, with C like syntax, but very simple (less than 10 possible functions). And their format constantly defines. So I've decided not to use complex parsers, like pycparser etc, but parse things (only need a few info) with 're' module.
So, if I have:

```
# id = AddStrucEx (-1, "struct_MTRR", 0);
```

then I parse it like:

```
mkstruct_re = re.compile("""
    (?m)                                # Multiline
    ^[ \t]*id[ \t]*=[ \t]*AddStrucEx[ \t]*\(
    [ \t]*-1[ \t]*,[ \t]*
    "(?P<sname>.*)"                     # Structure name
    [ \t]*\,[ \t]*0
    [ \t]*\);[ \t]*$
""", re.VERBOSE)
mkstruct_group_name = dict([(v,k) for k,v in mkstruct_re.groupindex.items()])
mkstruct = mkstruct_re.finditer(idc)
for match in mkstruct :
    s = Struct()
    for group_index,group in enumerate(match.groups()) :
        if group :
            if mkstruct_group_name[group_index+1] == "sname" :
                s.name = group
    structs.append(s)
```

But what I'm need to do, for parsing such thing:

```
# Case 1: not nested structures
# =============================
# id = GetStrucIdByName ("struct_header");
# mid = AddStructMember(id,"BCPNV", 0, 0x5000c500, 0, 7);
# mid = AddStructMember(id,"_", 0X7, 0x00500, -1, 1);
# mid = AddStructMember(id, "BCPNV_size",0X8, 0x004500, -1, 1);
```

Where "struct_header" - name of the structure, and other - its members. For example member one - name "BCPNV", type 0, size 0x5000c500.
So I'm need to fill struct with members, here is pseudocode:

```
s = get_struct_by_name("struct_header")
...
member = Member(name, type, size)
s.append(member)
```

Such pattern repeats over all file. So I need somehow write regex, which can handle this as one multiline string.

Comment: can you tell us what you want to extract from the case 1 example and what the regularities are?

Comment: Updated with this information